# Send individual array results to printer based on id table

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, printing

I'm working on a simple PHP script that stores user details in a MySQL database. I can run a query and have it return the individual records as long as the query matches the last name (pre-defined). Once I have the records, I want to be able to echo a print button next to each record so that the user can individually print each record.

The code is a mashup of several snippets of code and is working great, except the "print user data" part. I'm not a newbie in PHP, but I also know enough to navigate around a script. Here's what I've got so far.

```
<?php
//capture search term and remove spaces at its both ends if the is any
$searchTerm = trim($_GET['keyname']);

//check whether the name parsed is empty
if($searchTerm == "")
{
echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
exit();
}

//database connection info
$host = "localhost"; //server
$db = "users"; //database name
$user = "root"; //dabases user name
$pwd = "password1"; //password

//connecting to server and creating link to database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

//MYSQL search statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE lastname LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* check whether there were matching records in the table
by counting the number of results returned */
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
{
$output = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{

        echo "<tr valign=bottom>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=#ffffff background='img/dots.gif' colspan=6><img     src=img/blank.gif width=1 height=1></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr valign=center>";
    echo "<td class=tabval><img src=img/blank.gif width=10 height=20></td>";

    echo "<td class=tabval><b>".htmlspecialchars($row['firstname'])."</b> </td>";
    echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['lastname'])."&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['address'])."</td> ";
    echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['phone'])."&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"formbutton\" onclick=\"printpage('" .     $lastname . "'); \">Print User Data</button>";



    echo "<td class=tabval></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;

}
echo "<tr valign=bottom>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=#fb7922 colspan=6><img src=img/blank.gif width=1 height=8></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo $output;

}
else
echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;
?>


<br />
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Done</a>
```

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don't create gigantic [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like you have here. You're using `mysqli` so you should be adding data with the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method. There's no excuse for using string concatenation.

Comment: Even though this script is for an intranet page, I'll see about hardening the security aspect of it. Thanks

Comment: It's not just about security. It's about not blowing up when someone types in `Bob's Uncle` as a search term. What you have here is a bug, plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"formbutton\" onclick=\"printpage('" .     $lastname . "'); \">Print User Data</button>";`

This line is calling a javascript function called "printpage". Once you have that javascript function on the page, you'll be closer to your expected result.

Comment: Somehow, the script didn't survive the cut & paste. It's there in the original code, just not showing up here for some reason. The only result I get from pushing the "print user data" button is the whole page is sent to the printer, not individual records like I need them to.